# How SELECT many tags on a Table and save it on a List<string>

Tags: c#, sql-server, select, ado.net

I want to know how i can take it all the tags that i have on my table and save it on a list.

```
string query = "SELECT JobNumber + JobName + JobTag FROM dbo.Cat05Projects WHERE JobNumber = @JobNumber AND JobTag = @JobTag";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("JobNumber", JobNumber);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("JobTag", JobTag);

SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.HasRows)
{
     while (reader.Read())
     {
         tags.Add(reader[0].ToString());
         tags.Add(reader[1].ToString());
         tags.Add(reader[2].ToString());

     }
 }
```

Comment: Hi Angel, welcome to stackoverflow, Do you want to get all **Distinct** `jobTags` from your table, or you want JobNumber, jobName along with JobTag

Comment: Related - don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I wanted

```
query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Cat05Projects WHERE JobNumber = @JobNumber AND JobTag = @JobTag";
                command = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("JobNumber", JobNumber);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("JobTag", JobTag);

                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        lista.Add(reader[i].ToString());
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

due to your concatenation `(JobNumber + JobName + JobTag)` it is not possible to use `reader[X].ToString()` because just a single string is going to be returned. In order to fetch records properly you have to use **comma** instead of **plus** as below.

```
string query = "SELECT JobNumber , JobName , JobTag FROM dbo.Cat05Projects WHERE JobNumber = @JobNumber AND JobTag = @JobTag";
```

You did not mention anything about **`tags`** data structure, but if i am not mistaken, after getting the correct response, if you are trying to fetch only 
**JobTag** you can use LINQ to filter the final list.

Comment: I mean, my tags are the Columns of my SQL Table